# Всплывает окно, но его не видно - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не всплывает окно для заказа, в консоли ошибок не выскакивает, просто выводиться блок. Видно по верстке и по инспектору, внутри него все есть, но блок не видно. В css смотрел - `display:none` нету /  `z-index` не хочет срабатывать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
}, t = [], r = ".modal-content, .sweet-overlay, .sweet-alert, #cboxOverlay, #colorbox", plp.modal = {
init: function(e, n) {

    try {
      var r;
      return r = !1, e.on("click", function(e) {

        try {
          return r === !1 && (n.appendTo("div.area"), n.modal({
                backdrop: !1,
                keyboard: !1,
                show: !1
              }),
              r = !0),
            n.modal("show"), n.before('<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>'), t.push(n), plp.lazy.update(),
            n.find(".widget-slider").length && n.find(".bxslider").trigger("openModal"), e.preventDefault()
        } catch (o) {
          error_handler(o, "red libs 5", arguments.callee)
        }
      })
```

```html
<div class="macros-modal">
  <div class="modal fade nocolors" data-modal="form" area-context="uid5">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 274px;z-index: 99999;">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button class="close nofonts">
                                                                                                            ×
                                                                                                        </button>
      <h4 class="textable">
        <p style="text-align: center;">
          <strong><span
                                                                                                                        style="font-size: 22px;"><span
                                                                                                                        style="font-family: &quot;Roboto Slab&quot;;">Заявка&nbsp;</span></span></strong><br><strong><span
                                                                                                                    style="font-size: 22px;"><span
                                                                                                                    style="font-family: &quot;Roboto Slab&quot;;">на <strong><span
                                                                                                                    style="font-size: 22px;"><span
                                                                                                                    style="font-family: &quot;Roboto Slab&quot;;">JBL charge</span></span></strong></span>
          </span>
          </strong>
        </p>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="macros-form">
        <div class="outer">
          <div class="inner">
            <div class="vertical none size-default">
              <div class="body">
                <div class="cont"></div>
                <form action="https://блютуз-колонки.рф/" class="form text-top" data-form="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Заказ&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;order&quot;,&quot;privacy&quot;:&quot;text&quot;,&quot;privacy_checkbox&quot;:&quot;Даю согласие на <обработку персональных данных>&quot;,&quot;after&quot;:&quot;msg&quot;,&quot;msg&quot;:&quot;Спасибо!\nВаша заявка отправлена.\nВ ближайшее время мы с Вами свяжемся!&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;/&quot;,&quot;addhtml&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;js&quot;:&quot;alert(\&quot;Этот код выполняется после успешного отправления заявки.\&quot;);&quot;,&quot;integrations&quot;:[]}"
                  data-fields="[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Имя&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;name&quot;,&quot;required&quot;:true,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;&quot;},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Телефон&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;phone&quot;,&quot;required&quot;:true,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;&quot;},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Модель&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;radio-list&quot;,&quot;required&quot;:false,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;&quot;}]">
                  <div class="fields">
                    <div class="field" data-type="name">
                      <div class="name">
                        Имя<span class="required">&nbsp;*</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="input">
                        <input value="" class="form-control text" style="border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field" data-type="phone">
                      <div class="name">
                        Телефон<span class="required">&nbsp;*</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="input">
                        <input value="" class="form-control text" style="border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field" data-type="radio-list">
                      <div class="name">
                        Модель
                      </div>
                      <div class="input"><label><input name="radio1" value="JBL charge 2+" type="radio"> JBL  charge 2+</label><label>
                                                                                                                                            <input  name="radio1" value="JBL charge 3+"  type="radio"> JBL charge 3+</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="macros-button">
                    <div class="btn-out full xs-none">
                      <div class="btn-inner">
                        <button class="btn font-text submit" id="uid6" data-ym_goal="" data-ga_category="" data-ga_action="">
                                                                                                                                                <span class="text">Заказать!</span><input
                                                                                                                                                    type="submit">
                                                                                                                                            </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
                <div class="agreement-text">
                  <span>Нажимая кнопку, вы даете согласие на <a
                                                                                                                                        class="btn-modal agreement-link"
                                                                                                                                        data-modal="agreement">обработку персональных данных</a></span>
                </div>
                <div class="cont"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы не весь код предоставили для воспроизведения проблемы

Comment: я уже и не знаю что еще предоставить

Comment: Почитайте про [mcve]

Comment: посмотрите свойства left  и top объекта, transform.... возможно там сделана плавность появления но что-то не срабатывает... посмотрите на родительском overflow:hidden

Comment: нужен html, как появляется окно, если по клику то добавьте кнопку + css все что касается появления исчезания окна, js добавьте джиквери и если плагин используете то и плагин (с cdnjs можно взять)

Comment: На самом деле нужно копать в сторону `opacity` и `visiblity`